# SSH returns: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss

Tags: ssh

I am accustomed to using Putty on a Windows box or an OSX command line terminal to SSH into a NAS, without any configuration of the client.

Ubuntu 16.04 attempts to SSH into the NAS (via LAN):

```
ssh root@192.168.8.109

Unable to negotiate with 192.168.8.109 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss
```

1. Is this result / response intentional?
2. Is there a simple correction that enables SSH access to the NAS?

Comment: You didn't have any SSH private key (`.pem`) files on your Windows machine, did you?

Comment: No .pem files on Windows box

Comment: Your NAS wouldn't happen to be a Western Digital EX-series would it? :)

Comment: It is a MyCloud device: hope that somehow clarifies

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208495/unable-to-negotiate-with-xx-xxx-xx-xx-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-of and specially https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/112802/why-openssh-deprecated-dsa-keys

Answer (score 511, accepted):

The version of OpenSSH included in 16.04 disables ssh-dss. There's a neat page with legacy information that includes this issue: http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html

In a nutshell, you should add the option `-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss` to the SSH command:

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss root@192.168.8.109
```

---

You can also add a host pattern in your `~/.ssh/config` so you don't have to specify the key algorithm every time:

```
Host nas
  HostName 192.168.8.109
  HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss
```

This has the added benefit that you don't need to type out the IP address. Instead, `ssh` will recognize the host `nas` and know where to connect to. Of course you can use any other name in its stead.

Comment: I believe that these are solutions on the Ubuntu side.  Is there a simple  option on the NAS side?  It would be nice to understand all options and seize the opportunity to harden any security weakness.    Maybe this is another question for another thread?  Very nice explanation \ response

Comment: Is it possible to set this globally? LIke wildcard IP? 0.0.0.0 doesn't work

Comment: @podarok, try `Host *`

Comment: If you're also seeing `DH GEX group out of range`: https://serverfault.com/a/809082/55544

Comment: The latest OpenSSH version disables RSA, if you run into the error now, you should use `+ssh-rsa` instead of `+ssh-dss`

Comment: @Kale Elmer : How to make the same command as passwordless  ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss root@192.168.8.109

Comment: Your inline flag also works for SFTP over SSH: `sudo sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa username@ipaddress`

Answer (score 149):

If you came here because Bitbucket returns the following after an update to OpenSSH 8.8:

```
Unable to negotiate with <ip address> port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

you should *NOT* enable DSS (like in the accepted answer), but rather RSA in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

**Reference:** https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-articles/OpenSSH-8-8-client-incompatibility-and-workaround/ba-p/1826047

Note that `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` is a backwards compatible alias to  `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` which has been suggested in the article. If you use it, the same configuration can be used with older OpenSSH client versions, e.g. if you share the config with docker containers.

You can do the same for other hosts, or use `Host *` to allow RSA for any host.

Comment: To test on the command line, add this to your `ssh` command: `-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -oPubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa ` If that works, edit `~/.ssh/config` as described above for that host.

Comment: Did not work for talking to my aging Western Digital NAS.

Comment: Worked for my APC Smart-UPS 1000 SMT1000RM2U on firmware UPS 15.0 (ID18)

Answer (score 25):

If you want to use newer OpenSSH to connect to deprecated servers:

```
ssh -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss my.host.com
```

Add `-v` if you want to see what's happening, and `-o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss` if it still doesn't work:

```
ssh -v -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 my.host.com
```

You can also edit `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/ssh_config` and add:

```
Host my.host.com *.myinsecure.net 192.168.1.* 192.168.2.*
    HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-dss
    KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

https://forum.ctwug.za.net/t/fyi-openssh-to-access-rbs-openssh-7/6069 mentions  the following fix on Mikrotik Routerboards:

```
/ip ssh set strong-crypto=yes
```

(Noting this here because this answer also comes up on web searches when looking for a similar error message.)

Comment: it should be -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 (not 14)

Comment: That depends...

$ ssh -Q kex server
diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
ecdh-sha2-nistp256
ecdh-sha2-nistp384
ecdh-sha2-nistp521
curve25519-sha256@libssh.org

Comment: Thanks for the Mikrotik info.  Sadly it only works on RouterOS 6.31 onwards.  (Mine is on a remote site and I don't fancy trying a remote upgrade in case something goes wrong...)

Comment: It should definitely work on older Mikrotik too, you just have to find a supported key algo, just try a few of the ones listed with ssh -Q kex - and definitely add ssh-dss. You definitely should upgrade your router, because it's trivial to log into 6.31 without any password at all, so the risk of someone else locking you out is quite high - I hope it doesn't have internet access! If it does, log into it and /sys package update download; /reboot. If you can't ssh, try telnet or mactelnet.

Comment: If adding `KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1` is more secure with than without, this answer should be the accepted answer

Comment: nice! I have received the error "Protocol error: no matching DH grp found". Adding -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 helped! (even if it is just a workaround)

Answer (score 23):

Create new file with *.conf extension in /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/my.conf
```

add to new empty line:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.02.

Comment: You really shouldn't be editing system-wide configuration files when you can just edit the `$HOME/.ssh/config` file for your own user instead.

Answer (score 18):

Editing the ~/.ssh/config file is the best option. 
If you have a number of hosts to connect to on the same subnet you can use the following method to avoid entering each host in the file:

```
 Host 192.168.8.*
  HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss
```

This works great for me as I have a number of Brocade switches to manage and they started complaining about the Host key after I moved to Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 11):

For me [this added into `.ssh\config` worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38325640/4970442):

```
Host *
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-dss
```

Comment: Simple and working. Sometimes you just want a quick solution.

Answer (score 2):

Running this one-liner on client worked to workaround the issue:

> echo -e "Host *\nHostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa\nPubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa\n"|sudo tee -a ~/.ssh/config

Answer (score 2):

The 'their offer' list of algorithms are the ones that the server will accept so the client needs to offer matching ones. As mentioned one way to fix this is add the missing algorithms to your `.ssh/config` file. If it still doesn't work it is worth checking which algorithms your version of ssh has to offer:

```
ssh -Q key
```

If you do not see the missing algorithm listed from this command then you will need update your ssh version.

But if you do see the missing algorithm there then it's possible that either the system `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file and/or `/Users/USERNAME/.ssh/config` contains a `HostkeyAlgorithms` line that limits the number of algorithms. This can happen if the algorithms are listed without `+` prefix which will then lead to ssh only offering those on that list e.g. (`HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dsa`) so this can be fixed by just commenting that line, or explicitly adding the specific missing algorithms. The `+` prefix will add one or more algorithms to the list.

Answer (score 2):

I can't change anything on the server: I  created a script called `ssh` in my home directory which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-dss $1
```

I can invoke:

```
./ssh username@host
```

as before.

Comment: It is much preferable to use the ~/.ssh/config file, it allows you to define the user during connection. (see https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/)

Answer (score 1):

I have a different approach since I am working with many different embedded linux systems at work.
First I had a script, similar to MichaelM's answer, but I created a special alias that runs ssh with the added parameters (`-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa`)

```
alias sshrsa='function __sshrsa() { PARAM=$*; [ -z "$PARAM" ] && return 1; ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa ${PARAM}; unset -f __sshrsa; }; __sshrsa'
```

For this, the alias creates a private function that is then called. This makes it possible to use alias with additional input, which isn't usually supported with alias.

This way I can invoke for example

```
sshrsa <user>@<host>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1288219)

Comment: if you need to log in on many different machines, then the ~/.ssh/config file is your friend and your alias is useless. (see https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/)