# Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04

Tags: ssh, encryption, rsync

Up until last week I was running Ubuntu 20.04 happily, and then over the weekend decided to back everything up and install 22.04.  I've had a couple of teething issues which I've solver, however I'm having real issues with SSH.  I have two first generation WD MyCloud drives which handle all my backups and files both on and away from home.  I can still connect to the shares with no problems, however I need to SSH onto both drives in order to run maintenance, backup between cloud drives, etc.

Initially I couldn't gain SSH access at all after upgrading, however the one-fix at this website worked.  I can now connect via SSH and entering a password.

However with Ubuntu 20.04 I had set up a passphrase so that various autyomated scripts that I use using rsync could copy between cloud drives and also between Ubuntu and the cloud drive shares.  This was working until I upgraded, now the scripts continually ask me for my password and I can't figure out how to stop it.

What I was originally doing was running

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

to generate a passphrase and then

```
ssh-copy-id root@server
```

to copy the passphrase across

If I then entered

```
ssh root@server
```

it simply connected without asking to my password.

I know this is going to be due to my cloud drives only supporting the now insecure SSH, but I cannot upgrade it to a more secure one (unless someone knows how - I would prefer to do this to be honest).  My maintenance scripts can make up to 20 connections over a period of hours, and to have to sit and constantly enter the password is becoming a pain.

Can anyone help me get my remote rsync commands working again so they don't keep asking me for my password

The terminal outputs as I run through these are

```
colin@colin-desktop:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -b 4096

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/colin/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/colin/.ssh/id_rsa
Your public key has been saved in /home/colin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx colin@colin-desktop
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
...
+----[SHA256]-----+

colin@colin-desktop:~/.ssh$ ssh-copy-id root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 1 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password: 

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with:   "ssh 'root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.

colin@colin-desktop:~/.ssh$ ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password: 

Linux NASServer 3.2.26 #1 SMP Thu Jul 9 11:14:15 PDT 2015 wd-2.4-rel armv7l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.

NASServer:~# cd ~/.ssh

NASSERVER:~/.ssh# ls -al

total 12
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 May 17 23:32 .
drwx------ 7 root root 4096 Apr 28 19:02 ..
-rw------- 1 root root  742 May 17 23:32 authorized_keys

NASServer:~/.ssh# exit

logout
Connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.

colin@colin-desktop:~$ rsync --verbose --archive -e 'ssh -p 22' ~/Files/ root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/shares/Files/

root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

How this originally came about was that I needed to be able to rsync to and from a remote location without the need for a human intervention regarding security. The instructions I was given were to use ssh-keygen to generate public/private keys and then ssh-copy-id to copy the public key to the remote host.  I've just reinstalled 20.04 on another machine and used this successfully and the rsync is working without the need for a password.  However if I clear the keys on the server out, reinstall 22.04 and do the same, it still prompts me for the password.  I've updated my question to show the output of the commands as they are being run on Ubuntu 22.04 with the server name obscured for obvious reasons.

The Terminal output of rsync -vvv follows

```
colin@colin-desktop:~$ ssh -vvv root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/colin/.ssh/config
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com]
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/colin/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/colin/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/colin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22 as 'root'
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers ctos: 3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: 3des-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: 3des-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: 3des-cbc MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug2: bits set: 515/1024
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/colin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/colin/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/colin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 495/1024
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/colin/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/colin/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/colin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/colin/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing a passphrase with a keypair; the commands you showed create a RSA keypair and copy the public key to the root@server account. The authentication process will still ask you for a pass**phrase** to unlock the key (unless you chose an empty passphrase when you created the keypair).

Comment: @user68186 it's still possible that key-based authentication is failing altogether, and the OP is really being asked for the pass**word**. I guess another possibility may be that their old key had a passphrase, but that it was being loaded and unlocked automagically by the default keyring?

Comment: @steeldriver My apologies, you are quite correct about me confusing passphrase and keypair. It's been a long two days trying to sort this out.

Comment: @user68186 The root access is not for Ubuntu, but for the Debian running inside the Western Digital MyCloud NAS drive.  I know root is the least acceptable user to log in and perform tasks with, but it is also the least problematic on the drive, and it's also the one WD use for their first generation drives (this was corrected in the second generation).  I'm using root because it stops any issues which may be introduced by using another user account.

Comment: Thanks for posting the additional diagnostic information - we can now see that the authentication is indeed falling right through to password. You say that you know it's due to your "cloud drives only supporting the now insecure SSH" - how did you verify that? Have you run the ssh command with increased verbosity (`-v` or `-vv` or `-vvv`)? Can you see at what point exactly it's failing?

Comment: @steeldriver I've added the -vvv diagnostic.  I'm basing my assumption regarding insecure SSH on 3 things.  If I run ssh -v on the cloud drive itself I get "OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016". If I try to connect to the drive from Android I have to use SMB 1 (SMB 2 not supported), and Western Digital have been advising everyone to basically unplug their drives and buy new ones as they'd rather end support than roll out security updates [link](https://www.dpreview.com/news/3393771024/western-digital-is-ending-support-for-older-versions-of-my-cloud-os-affecting-many-products)

Comment: OK thanks - does it make any difference if you add `-o 'KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'` to the ssh command?

Comment: @steeldriver Nope, no change whatsoever.  I'm still being asked for the password in order to connect via ssh or rsync.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for posting a solution ... and ... nope, still not working, SSH and RSYNC are studiously asking me for a password everytime.  I'm happy to keep going if you are, or we can just call it a day and I'll roll back to Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @Colin the posted answer is not mine - I saw the big bold **SOLUTION** and thought *you'd* found the solution and posted it yourself ...

Comment: @steeldrive Ah, I never spotted that it was user68186 either, sorry.

Comment: @user68186 Sorry, the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Colin Does the "Workaround" work?

Comment: @user68168 My sincerest apologies. The workaround did when I finally remembered to reboot the computer, it's been a long day!  Many MANY thanks for helping me past all of this.  It's a shame I can't update the cloud drives to RSA SHA-2 or SHA-3, but sadly Western Digital have decided to end support rather than fixing it.  However at least I can run my rsync scripts unattended again until I can afford to upgrade to a newer model of cloud drive.  Thanks again.

Comment: No need to apologize. It is a shame that the WD cloud drive does not accept `ed25519` keys. Anyways, I am happy your problem is solved for now.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

## Cause

The RSA SHA-1 hash algorithm is being quickly deprecated across operating systems and SSH clients because of various security vulnerabilities, with many of these technologies now outright denying the use of this algorithm.

It seems this has happened for the `ssh` client in Ubuntu 22.04. The RSA public-private key pair is considered **not safe any more**.

## Solution

Use a more modern and secure type of key such as `ed25519`. Generate a new key pair in your Ubuntu 22.04 computer with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "colin@colin-desktop"
```

**Note:** the string after `-C` is a comment it is customary to put your email address here. Since you may only be using this key within your home, putting the email address may not make sense. I would put something like "colin@colin-desktop" so that you know which user and computer the key belongs to within your household.

**Alternately** you may create a new RSA key with SHA2 hashing like so:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa-sha2-512 -b 4096
```

Either way you will need to use the `ssh-copy-id` command again:

```
ssh-copy-id root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This command will recognize there is a new public key and copy the new key to the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

It should work now.

## A Remote Server Workaround

If you can't change anything on the local computer, or don't want to use a new key, and want to re-enable RSA on the local computer, edit the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote computer and add this line:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

This will allow the use of unsafe RSA key you already have.

Remember to restart the sshd service by:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Otherwise you will have to **restart your computer** to make the change take effect.

## References

- [SSH-RSA key rejected with message "no mutual signature algorithm"](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html)
- [OpenSSH 8.3 released (and ssh-rsa deprecation notice)](https://lwn.net/Articles/821544/)
- [HostKeyAlgorithm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679451/sshd-no-hostkey-alg-fixed-but-still-confused)

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not about "unsafe RSA key". There's nothing wrong with the keys files. It's about internal hashing in SSH protocol. You can keep your keys, just upgrade your SSH client software to versions that support rsa-sha2-256/512. Even the OpenSSH 8.3 release notes you link in your question say that: *"These
   algorithms have the advantage of using the same key type as
   "ssh-rsa" but use the safe SHA-2 hash algorithms"*

Comment: @pimpo I have added the rsa-sha2-512 option in the answer.

Comment: it seems that you have to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config, not /etc/ssh/ssh_config. You should fix the answer.

Comment: It's also enough to restart sshd service, something like "systemctl restart sshd", no need to reboot

Comment: You make my day! Replacing `RSA` key with `ed25519` resolved the problem.

Comment: Creating a new key seemed to work on my system, but when I enter "ssh-copy-id root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" then nothing will happen, the command does not finish until I press Ctrl-C. Then I get 5 error messages: Directory nonexistent, No such file or directory, No such file.

Comment: @w-sky This answer won't work for you as you are not using keys. You are using a password. I am not sure why you get these errors.

Comment: @pimpo in some cases, we don't (easily) have that option. I have an old ReadyNAS that has an OS based on Debian Jessie. It doesn't understand `rsa-sha2-512`, but *does* know about `ed25519`

Comment: @user68186 -- Please add `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa` to the section of the answer relating to editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (which is the name of the file on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) as to the tail-end of the stanza for the `Host *` entry.  Just adding `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa` is insufficient.

Comment: @lawlist Done the requested changes. Note, I am recommending changing the `/etc/shh/sshd_config` in the remote server and not changing the `/etc/shh/ssh_config` in the local client.

Comment: I couldn't get any of this to work with my Godaddy `OpenSSH_5.3p1` server with Ubuntu 22. I thought messing with the client configuration would give me a workaround but I can't figure it out. It still works with my old Mac OS X ssh client `8.1`

Comment: As @pimpo stated you can upgrade your SSH client to see if they can support the newer hashing. This was the answer for me. Upgraded my putty client from 0.70 to 0.79 allowed me to connect to my 22.04 instance with the same RSA key.

Answer (score 15):

When I need to re-enable a deprecated method in order to connect to a server I can't upgrade (e.g. an embedded legacy device such as an old router) I rather like doing this on a per-device basis instead of a general setting. Instead of /etc/ssh/ssh_config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/somefile.conf, I put this in a dedicated "Host ..." section (see ssh_config man) in my ~/.ssh/config file this way :

```
...
Host my.remote.server
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
Port 32579
OtherKeyword ...

Host otherserver
...
```

Notice I had to add *KexAlgorithms* and *HostKeyAlgorithms* keywords with relevant parameters along with suggested by user68186 *PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes* which was not enough. This is with Ubuntu 22.04 OpenSSH v8.9...

Comment: In my case I did not need `KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1` (ubuntu 22.04, `OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`), but did need both `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` and `HostKeyAlgorithms`.

Comment: i get this error `Load key "/home/sytel/.local/share/juju/ssh/juju_id_rsa.pub": error in libcrypto`

Comment: @shorif2000 you should open the private key instead of the public one (juju_id_rsa dot nothing by default). And check permissions : folder should be 700. Private keys 600 (or 400 if you never want to change comment or password of the key). You may also use **ssh -vvv** to get more info on the error.

Comment: @useful I can do `juju ssh kubernetes-worker/0` it works but not the normal ssh

Comment: I don't understand your command line. What is this juju command? How can this "work" without an alias line `alias juju="...."` in ~/.bash_aliases?

Answer (score 8):

similar problem, from a symfony PHP script on a Debian 11 to an SSH Ubuntu 22 server... I had to add the following **two** lines

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

without HostKeyAlgorithms it didn't work.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS when editing `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and adding those two entries to the tail-end of the stanza for `Host *`

Comment: It works on Ubuntu 22.10 too

Comment: note editing directly `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` should be avoided, and rather you should this config into the directory `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d` in a file with a extension `.conf`

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a similar problem after I upgraded my server from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. My Brother ADS-2400N document scanner suddenly refused to talk to my server via SFTP.

It turned out that this document scanner talks DSA and RSA *only*. This applies to both the server's public key, as well as the scanner's user public key.

In order to get it to work again, I had to add *three* lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
HostbasedAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

(Experiments with `ssh-sha2-512` and `ssh-sha2-256` were not successful.)

Too bad Brother apparently aren't upgrading the firmware for this model any more...

Answer (score 2):

Adding the line:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
```

to the end of /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restarting ssh.service solved it for me.

Comment: That's what the answer by @user68186 says already.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Nope, user68186  state to add two lines, not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

Passing in the cipher worked for me:

```
ssh -c aes256-gcm@openssh.com user@host.com
```

For more details, refer to https://superuser.com/a/1828520/36590