# After upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04, getting ssh Permission denied (publickey) error

Tags: ssh, 22.04, 21.10, openssh, sshd

Immediately following my upgrade to Ubuntu **22.04** from **21.10**, I can no longer connect to Google Cloud Platform via ssh and am receiving the following error (e.g. after running `git clone`):

```
john@doe.com@source.developers.google.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I'm asking here because it seems directly related to the upgrade (though could be coincidence), and I'm wondering if ssh standard/methods changed in Ubuntu **22.04** that could be causing this, though several searches on this were unsuccessful.

In addition to hours of searching and reviewing all other **Ask Ubuntu** questions related to `Permission denied (publickey).`, I've tried the following:

Confirm ssh agent is running:
`eval $(ssh-agent -s)`

Add key to agent:
`ssh-add` (equivalent to `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`)

Show sha256 of public key:
`ssh-add -l` (output on my machine matches sha256 sum displayed by Google in **Manage SSH Keys**)

Generated new keys and tested those:
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "220608_test"`

Tried restarting/enabling/starting ssh:
`sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`
`sudo systemctl enable ssh.service`
`sudo systemctl start ssh.service`

Checked permissions:
Permission of `~/.ssh/` folder: `700` i.e. `rwx------`
Permission of private key in `~/.ssh/`: `600` i.e. `rw-------`
Permission of public key in `~/.ssh/`: `644` i.e. `rw-r--r--`

I also tested changing the public key to 600 permissions:
`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Determined firewall status is inactive per:
`sudo ufw status`

I've never needed to specify connection parameters for Google Cloud in `~/.ssh/config`.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks similar to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04/1409528#1409528). See if that answer helps you.

Comment: Perfect! I generated a key with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "john@doe.com"`, and that did the trick. Thank you. Feel free to add an answer and I'll select it, or maybe my q should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I am voting to close this as a duplicate of [Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04)