# connect to host ssh connection timed out

Tags: ssh

On a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04 I can not connect to my servers from terminal using ssh.

I use this command as I have always done for almost 10 years.

```
ssh user@host -p55555
```

After some time the server replies:

```
ssh: connect to host 11.22.33.44 port 12345: Connection timed out
```

I tried to see if there is an active firewall but I can find any.

Do I have to config something new in this version to have access to my servers?

From dolphin explorer I can perfectly connect with the same servers using ftps.

Comment: Your details are either not clear, incorrect, or contradictory.  Specifically, there is a problem with the port you are indicating. The default port for ssh is 22. Your command is incorrect at `-p55555`.  Is this a typo? If your ssh server is on port 55555, you need to add a space `-p 55555`. Also, your ssh connection error message says you are trying to connect to port 12345. Which is it? If your ssh server is on port 22 you do not need to use the `-p` tag at all. If it's on another port you need to use the correct port in your command and the syntax must be correct

Comment: Thank for your replay. Of course my server is lessening to the correct port ,the 12345 was an example ... and the command that i wrote is correct, with the other hard disk (the old one still in use)  connect ,the space is no necessary connect as well without space .... this problem is only in the 22.04 version at least in my two hard disk that I been prepare. I relay do not know why in this two hard disk in two different machine doesn't work. that why i ask her for help

Comment: I don't see how any characteristics of a hard drive could possibly have anything to do with your ability to connect over ssh. Can you please edit your question so that the details are at least consistent with each other? If you can connect to the same server on other devices, this sounds like a networking problem and probably has nothing to do with the version of Ubuntu you are using. It definitely doesn't have anything to do with your hard drive. Is the server on the same local network as the client? Does it need to be?

Comment: You are probably right, but I do no not see thing wrong on my network configuration, Thank for your replay. again .in fact I have try to connect local machine in port 22 and it do work well. but when I try to go out to my many servers do not work, I also try to connect with wire not wifi and still not working ... tomorrow I will look at the net configuration. But I still not understand why default configuration not working. thank you very much

Comment: Port 22 is the default port for ssh. If you can connect on port 22 and not other ports it's because your ssh server is listening on 22 and not on the other port. You'll need to configure your ssh server to listen on another port if you want to connect over that port

Comment: Sorry but not ... all server that we got running are lissening well at the port on my ssh command as I said before we do this from years only with this version fail I can tell you that the 21.10 works that my wondering

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is but the Ubuntu version is not the only variable and I'm certain that it's not the Ubuntu version to blame. All I can say is to check your network and ssh configurations

Comment: See this answer: [Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me.  When checking the status of the `ufw` firewall (to make sure it was off), I noticed an error stating that `/` was owned by a user other than `0`. Looks like the upgrade changed ownership to my personal user. I changed it back to `root:root` and now SSH and Samba work again.