# Can not connect with Files to SFTP after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, sftp, nemo, seahorse

Until I recently upgraded my machine from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 I always could connect to SFTP folders with Nemo or Nautilus easily. I am using a connection with username and password and the password is stored locally in keyring (Seahorse), so I just enter "sftp://name@server.com/folder" into the location et voilà.

Nemo now says "Could not display "sftp://name@server.com/folder" – Error: Connection failed" and Nautilus is similar: "Oops! Something went wrong. Unhandled error message: Connection failed".

It does work when I use FTP instead of SFTP. However I prefer to use SFTP. Why is it not working anymore and how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04) I guess this is your problem. If not, update the question with what happens if you try to use the `ssh -vvv remote_user@remote_address` from the terminal.

Comment: To be clear SFTP uses `ssh` in the background. So, I am guessing the root problem is with `ssh`. I assume you are using a private-public authentication key pair instead of a password. If you use a password instead of a key, then update the question with that information.

Comment: Thanks @user68186, I tried the solution at the linked question but unsuccessful, the last command always fails. (I also commented on it there.) I also updated my question here; yes I am using a (S)FTP connection with username & password.

Comment: Now I see the context of the your comment to the answer to the linked question. My assumptions about your question were wrong. This is not a duplicate of the other question. I am retracting my close vote. Since you are using a password and seahorse, the problem is not with private and public keys. The problem is probably with seahorse.

Comment: It will great if you can open a terminal and enter: `ssh -vvv name@server.com` or `ssh -vvv root@server.com`, whichever you use. Let me know if it asks for the password or 'name` or `root`. If login to server.com fails, copy all the output of the `ssh` command and paste it in your question above. Then format the pasted output as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit question widow.