# Problem connecting via SSH after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 using outdated WinSCP - version 5.13.4

Tags: server, upgrade, ssh

We had to update a web server to get ahead of several EOL issues related to software we were running. Now that we have upgraded, our client is unable to connect to pick up files they need to pick up on a cron schedule. They are currently using WinSCP version 5.13.4 and they're an enterprise-level client that can't just update these things easily.

We tested this issue using version 5.13.4 and received the exact same error they did:

> Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

We tested with the latest version of WinSCP (5.21.6) and were able to connect just fine.

Is there any way around this? I found this question and answer, but I'm unsure if it's the same issue because the latest version of WinSCP works: [Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409105/ubuntu-22-04-ssh-the-rsa-key-isnt-working-since-upgrading-from-20-04)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's likely the same issue *(post logs from both versions if you want to be certain)*.

WinSCP supports `rsa-sha2-256` and `rsa-sha2-512` since WinSCP 5.20 (December 2021):
https://winscp.net/tracker/1952

If you need to support older versions of WinSCP, you have to (re-)enable `ssh-rsa` on the server:

```
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Obviously, this is not recommended.