# ssh no matching host key type found

Tags: openssh

I have 2 Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS servers. Both are the same version.

1:**`chia@chia00:~$ cat /etc/os-release`**
`PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"`

2:**`chia@hp1:~$ cat /etc/os-release`**
`PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"`

When I try to ssh between the hosts I get the following error:
**`chia@hp1:~$ ssh chia00`**

`Unable to negotiate with 172.16.153.152 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

So, I did some reading and saw a suggestion to add the offered algorighm, but still didn't work. All that did was to change the "offer":
**`chia@hp1:~$ ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 chia00`**

`Unable to negotiate with 172.16.153.152 port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,spki-sign-rsa`

Interestingly, going from host 2 to host 1 works fine.

Comment: You will likely need to pass a -o`HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` option as well - see for example [SSH returns: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss](https://askubuntu.com/a/885396/178692)

Comment: ```chia@hp1:~$ ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 chia00```
```Unable to negotiate with 172.16.254.156 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but wasn't able to get through. Still getting same type of offer from remote host.: chia@hp1:~$ ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 chia00
Unable to negotiate with 172.16.254.156 port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,arcfour